# Android Pointer Events coordinates

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

I have a problem with **PointerEvents** on ***Android Chrome version 64.0.3282.137***.

In my solution i use `pointer` event with `html canvas`.
I capture event coordinates in canvas by `event.offsetX` and `event.offsetY` parameters. This working well in previous versions, but in this version coordinates are wrong.

This is reflected both in landscape and portrait mode, and only in Android version of Chrome. I tested it in *Huawei  M2*, *Samsung S6 Edge+*, *S8*.

It is a bug in this version?

Or is another possibility, how to get correct coordinates.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing the same issue for clientX and clientY. You can try touch event like "touchstart" and can use event.originalEvent.touches for the x and y coordinates.
Have opened a bug on chromium for it and it is accepted. This is the link : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=811715